# Redis EVAL-per-event or EVAL-all-events-at-once

Tags: redis, lua

If you have ~50 events/second, each event should be handled transactionaly (make 3 SADD operations), what is better:

1. Run one Lua script (via EVALSHA) per event?
2. Run single Lua script that will iterate all events and update them at once?

My considerations: single EVAL will be at least not slower than EVAL-per-event. The main cocern is script execution time. AFAIK, it sohuld block all operations accross all Redis namespaces. But I suppose I shouldn't be afraid of 150 SADD operations inside one EVAL, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better do some benchmark test with your production environment, although I think 150 operations are too many to block Redis for a while.

In fact, you have another alternative: run 50 Lua scripts in a [pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining). With pipeline, each of your Lua script won't block Redis for a long time, i.e. only 3 operations, and it saves lots of RTT, and should be much faster than 50 `EVALSHA` commands.